# How to print a file content on a text area?

Tags: java, javafx

I want to print the content of my file to my `JFXTextArea` but the output is not 100% the same.

**This is the file content:**

[image]

**This is the Output from my JavaFX program:**

[image]

and this is my code:

```
try {
    InputStream inputstream = new FileInputStream("output.txt");
    int data = inputstream.read();

    while (data != -1) {
        char aChar = (char) data;
        out.appendText(String.valueOf(aChar));
        System.out.print(aChar);
        data = inputstream.read();
    }

    inputstream.close();
} catch (Exception ex) {
    System.err.println(ex);
}
```

I tried the `BufferReader` and the `Scanner` but all of them get the same result.
Keep in mind that the output in the console is 100% equal to the file content.

[image]

Comment: It's because the font in your text editor and that of JavaFX application is not the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an issue of the font being used. Consoles mostly use monospaced fonts which work well when aligning characters. The default font JavaFX uses is not monospaced however.

You need to assign a font from this family yourself:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
    JFXTextArea textArea = new JFXTextArea();

    ToggleButton toggle = new ToggleButton("monospaced");
    toggle.setSelected(true);

    textArea.fontProperty().bind(
            Bindings.when(toggle.selectedProperty()).then(Font.font("monospaced")).otherwise(Font.getDefault()));

    textArea.setText(
            "+-----------+----------------------+\n"
          + "|   R1      |   R2                 |\n"
          + "+-----------+----------------------+\n"
          + "|  **DONE** |     ***DONE***       |\n"
          + "+-----------+----------------------+");

    stage.setScene(new Scene(new VBox(toggle, textArea)));
    stage.show();
}
```

Note that the binding is simply used to show the difference. Usually you simply set the font like this:

```
textArea.setFont(Font.font("monospaced"));
```

Comment: I just used this 
textArea.setFont(Font.font("monospaced"));
before I set the incoming data from the file (out.setText(data))
Thank you very much @fabian

Answer (score 0):

It's probably because you are using a different font in your JFXTextArea than in your text editor. Perhaps character-spacing also plays a role.

I suggest to first figure out what fonttype your text editor in which you made your file uses, and set the same font in Java.